# Why don't class name fallback to global class name in namespaces?

Tags: php, function, class, design-patterns, namespaces

I have been reading the [Using namespaces: fallback to global function/constant](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.fallback.php)  on php.net and it says the language is designed in the following way:

> Class names always resolve to the current namespace name. Thus to access internal or non-namespaced user classes, one must refer to them with their fully qualified Name.... .....For functions and constants, PHP will fall back to global functions or constants if a namespaced function or constant does not exist.

My question is what would be wrong if the classes could fallback to global classes, like functions and constants, when they are not defined in the current namespace? What would be the ideological or technical hardships of that design choice?

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with autoloading and performance.

From the [RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/namespaceresolution) about namespace resolution:

> One noteworthy aspect here is that for classes we have autoload. If
>   non fully qualified identifiers can be used to reference global
>   identifiers, “lazy” programmers can skip fully qualifying identifiers
>   even if they have the full intention of referencing a global
>   identifier. With autoload this could trigger expensive operations,
>   which are essentially useless.
>
> For functions however we do not have autoload capabilities. This
>   brings the advantage that falling back to the global namespace does
>   not run the performance risk of autoload. So a fallback would be much
>   less expensive, but there would still be overhead for not making
>   intentional references to the global namespace fully qualified.

Comment: I recently found out [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rules.php#example-269) that unqualified class names tries to autoload itself, if not defined in the current namespace. Which seems contradictory to what you are saying _"With autoload this could trigger expensive operations, which are essentially useless."_. And, may be my question is wrong too, because classes are being fallbacked.

Comment: Can you quote where you read that? Classes should not fallback. If I put a `class Exception {}` in the global scope, I should get an error, saying that I cannot re declare it

Comment: In the same example I linked in the comment above go to section _class references_ it says: `new B();    // creates object of class "B" defined in namespace "A"
            // if not found, it tries to autoload class "A\B"`

Comment: That's not falling back to the global namespace. That is "B" is not defined in namespace "A", so I try to autoload "B" in namespace "A". If the autoload doesn't find such class, it won't try to use the "A" class that exist in the global namespace.

Comment: I think I misunderstood the statement _With autoload this could trigger expensive operations, which are essentially useless._. I thought this means since autoloading is expensive, it is not used. I think it means, since classes use autoloading -- on top of that falling back to global namespace is an expensive operation.